# Alcatel Onetouch Idol 3 won't work with bluetooth

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth

I have an Alcatel Onetouch Idol 3 that I purchased in January.  It has static, breaks up and sounds muffled when I have my bluetooth on and wifi is on.  If I turn my wifi off it works ok. I have tried 4 bluetooth and returned the Alcatel once. Has anyone else had this problem or does anyone have a solution?  I am ready to cut my losses and purchase another phone.

Answer (score 0):

Wi-Fi and Bluetooth both operate in the 2.4 GHz frequency band.  As such, interference is to be expected; it's not your particular phone.  [Here is an interesting paper on it.](http://www.hp.com/rnd/library/pdf/WiFi_Bluetooth_coexistance.pdf)

You could see if your home Wi-Fi router supports the 5.0 GHz band, and switch to using that exclusively.  You could also try changing the [Wi-Fi channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the paper is from 2002 and this is the first time I have had this problem.  My router does support 5.0, however, the problem I have happens when I am in my car also, and there is no wifi, but my wifi is turned on on my phone.  The static is not just interference that can be overlooked, it is so bad that I would be repeating myself every few minutes or less and the same for the person on the other end.  It sounds like they are in water trying to talk.  I will try the 5.0 GHZ band at hoe and see if it makes a difference and update.